# Mikrotik API "no such command" when trying to get count-only of PPP connections

Tags: pppoe

I don't know if I'm posting in the right forum. But well correct me if I am wrong.

I am developing a service that counts the PPPoE users per MikroTik Device in the whole network every X minutes. I'm using the API build in Python3 (Although I think the problem is not language-dependent, but I tell you in order for you to know).

When I connect to a MKT, I can execute the command `ppp active print count-only`. In the API the language changes a bit. I can't execute that command. It tells me `=message=no such command prefix`. I've tried with `/ppp/active/print/count-only` but only works when I execute `/ppp/active/print` but that is not the result I want.

Thank you

Comment: If someone has provided an answer that resolves your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. This will reward both the person who provided the answer and yourself with additional reputation. If you do not do so, your question will periodically get refreshed back to the main page, possibly distracting community members from other questions they may be able to help answer for other users. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed a 2-line block of code

```
/ppp/active/print
=count-only=
```

Thank you